# How to tap on a submit button in the view without having to dismiss a keyboard first?

Tags: react-native, keyboard, textinput, onsubmit

I am using react native to implement a community feed. In each post in the feed, I can comment as seen below.

[image]

However, the issue is after I enter a comment and want to press on the submit icon on the right, the keyboard will dismiss first before I can tap on the icon to submit the text.

QUESTION:
How can I immediately submit my text after pressing the submit icon without tapping twice (once to dismiss the keyboard, and second to submit)

Here's a snippet of my implementation:
//Code for comments section/box

```
<View style={styles.commentSectionContainer}>
    <View style={[textInputStyle.dark, textInputStyle.compact]}>
      <LocalizedTextInput
        multiline={false}
        autoCorrect={true}
        onChangeText={onCommentTextChange}
        placeholder="placeholder/writeComment"
        style={[textInputStyle.default, {fontSize: 13}]}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        value={textComment}
        onSubmitEditing={() => {
          if (textComment) {
            onSubmitComment();
          }
        }}
        returnKeyType="send"
     />
     <View style={styles.iconSubmitContainer}>
      <IconButton style={styles.commentSubmit} iconName="send" isDisabled={textComment === ''} onPress={onSubmitComment} hitSlop={hitSlop} />
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Localized Text Input is using the following textinput

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <TextInput
    multiline={multiline}
    style={[defaultStyle, {flex: 1}]}
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    autoCorrect={true}
    {...otherProps}
  />
</View>
```

The posts are all wrapped in a scrollView.

I tried to use "keyboardShouldPersistTaps" and keyboardDismissMode="Drag-on" but it doesn't produce the expected experience.. The user should be able to dismiss the keyboard by tapping anywhere outside the textinput box instead of requiring to scroll.

Comment: where did you add "keyboardShouldPersistTaps". Is there any scrollview component in which this component is rendering. We should add "keyboardShouldPersistTaps" to scrollview.

Answer (score 3):

If your parent is a `ScrollView` component, then passing the prop `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` should do the  trick. See the official documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps).

Answer (score 1):

As Ankit suggested the prop needs to be passed to the scroll view but if that isn't giving you the desired results TextInput has a blur() method that you can call using a ref of that TextInput. Maybe that would help.